# Kulture error - kpm command not found

Tags: macos, mono, sublimetext3, asp.net-core, omnisharp

I recently installed Sublime Text 3 with the aim of coding some C# on the Mac. I then followed the steps on http://www.omnisharp.net for the installation of the plugins and everything works fine until I try to build a simple "HelloWorld" project. Then I get the error

> /Users/guevara/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Kulture/build.sh: line 21: kpm: command not found

I did check that I have the ASP.NET 5 KVM for MAC installed. Following the steps at http://www.enterpriseframework.com/post/2014/12/02/how-to-mac-vnext-step-by-step-setup-and-first-app also works, so the kpm command has been installed through Homebrew.

Any idea what I am doing wrong or why Kulture can't find the kpm command?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the last line of installing kvm on OS X instructions at https://github.com/aspnet/Home:

> Run command `source kvm.sh` on your terminal if your terminal cannot understand kvm.

but with the beta3 there's an issue in Kulture's `build.sh`, I have updated 4 1st lignes:

```
ver=`cat ~/.k/alias/default.alias`  
add_to_path=$HOME"/.k/runtimes/"$ver"/bin"  
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:$add_to_path  
[ -s $HOME"/.k/kvm/kvm.sh" ] && . $HOME"/.k/kvm/kvm.sh"
```

Comment: I had done that as well, runs without error. Doesn't help with the problem though.

Comment: check your KRE_HOME env var

Comment: did you untap aspnet?

Comment: I did untap it before tapping the new formula again and installing kvm with brew. Can you provide a more details on where/what I should check for the KRE_HOME env var? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `echo $KRE_HOME`, but did you try `kvm upgrade` ? it's missing in your tuto

Comment: I did do the kvm upgrade (successfully), it's in the steps for installation of ASP.NET from the first link. `echo $KRE_HOME` returns an empty string in the terminal though.

Comment: what this your `kvm list` output and check your PATH

Comment: `kvm list` delivers `Active Version              Runtime Location             Alias
------ -------              ------- --------             -----
  *    1.0.0-beta3          mono    ~/.k/runtimes        default
       1.0.0.-beta1         mono    ~/.k/runtimes        
       1.0.0.-beta2         mono    ~/.k/runtimes        `.
Checking the path delivers `/Users/alexguevara/.k/runtimes/kre-mono.1.0.0-beta3/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/texbin`

Comment: When trying to build the project, before the `kpm not found`, it also displays `cat: /Users/alexguevara/.kre/alias/default.alias: No such file or directory`.

Comment: I think there is an issue in the build.sh because all seems good in your config. it's not normal it look at .kre, it should be .k folder

Comment: Can you maybe post the code in your build.sh so that I can compare the two when I get home?

Comment: actualy, I totaly forgot, but I commented the 4 1st ligne in my build.sh, so it take the runtime I use with `kvm use`instead of default. I update my answer

Comment: Changing the lines in build.sh worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Aha, I found it; it says "runtime" in the build.sh file instead of "runtimes"; i couldn't see the issue for looking and no-one actually pointed out the specific mistake.